# In Microsoft Excel I have two lists with some cells equal to each other, how do find out which ones don't

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of total and then another list of summary totals
I need to find which cells in the total column don't match with the summary totals and the list is too large to do it all by eye and a calculator!
Here is the start of my totals list

```
275
815
1655
9783.46
3393
4487.26
1691
2376.66
1997
100
6167.91
675
8843
```

And my summary totals

```
1090
1655
9783.46
9571.26
2376.66
1997
100
620.3
15685.91
```

You can see why the 620.3 isn't matched yet:

```
Totals              Summary Totals
275+815             1090
1655                1655
9783.46             9783.46
3393+4487.26+1691   9571.26
2376.66             2376.66
1997                1997
100                 100
???                 620.3
6167.91+675+8843    15685.91
```

I need to find other like this.  Any formulas I can use?

Comment: Why isn't 620.3 matched yet? I do not quite understand your logic, so please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

## The VBA script

Stick this in a Module in the current workbook:

```
Function SummaryMatch(Totals As Range, SummaryTotals As Range) As Variant()
    Dim Sum As Double
    Dim T As Long, S As Long, I As Long
    Dim Result() As Variant
    Result = SummaryTotals.Value
    T = 1: S = 1
    Do
       If T > Totals.Rows.Count _
       Or S > SummaryTotals.Rows.Count _
       Then Exit Do

       Sum = 0: I = T
       Do
          Sum = Sum + Totals(I)
          I = I + 1
          If Abs(Sum - SummaryTotals(S)) < 0.001 Then
             Debug.Print SummaryTotals(S) & " T "
             Result(S, 1) = True
             T = I
             S = S + 1
             Exit Do
          ElseIf Sum > SummaryTotals(S) + 0.001 Then
             Debug.Print SummaryTotals(S) & " F "
             Result(S, 1) = False
             S = S + 1
             Exit Do
          End If
       Loop While True
    Loop While True
    SummaryMatch = Result
End Function
```

## How to use it

If your totals are in A2:A14 and you summary totals are in C2:C10 then you would highlight E2:E10 and enter =SummaryMatch(A2:A14,C2:C10) into E2 and press Control-Shift-Enter because the function returns an array.  The formula will display as {=SummaryMatch(A2:A14,C2:C10)} and will return a true/false value for each Summary Totals that indicates whether it has Totals that add up to that value or not.

```
    A        B        C        D         E 
1   Totals            Summary            Match
2   275               1090               TRUE
3   815               1655               TRUE
4   1655              9783.46            TRUE
5   9783.46           9571.26            TRUE
6   3393              2376.66            TRUE
7   4487.26           1997               TRUE
8   1691              100                TRUE
9   2376.66           620.3              FALSE
10  1997              5685.91            TRUE
11  100
12  6167.91
13  675
14  8843
```

## How it works

The script keeps an pointer to the two lists (T for the Totals list and S for the Summary Totals list) as well as an index (I) that scans forward through the Totals list.  Initially both T and S are set to start at the top (row 1 of each list) and then the loop is started.

The loop first checks whether we are at the bottom of one of the lists or not and then sets the current Sum to zero and starts scanning forward adding the current Total to the Sum and then comparing the Sum with the current Summary Total.

If the Sum matches the current Summary Total then we increment S to move to the next Summary Total and set the current Total to the current Index (so that we don't sum those values again) and then we start the main loop again.

If the Sum is more than the current Summary Total then the current Summary Total wasn't matched and we go on to the next one without changing the current Total to the current Indegx (so we start scanning at the current total again)

Answer (score 0):

Some newer versions of Excel have a "Remove Duplicates" function available in the Data menu. I pasted your list into Excel for Mac 2011, selected Remove Duplicates, and was left with the following data. Does this help?

`275
815
1655
9783.46
3393
4487.26
1691
2376.66
1997
100
6167.91
675
8843
And my summary totals
1090
9571.26
620.3
15685.91`

If necessary you could first Remove Duplicates within each group and then Remove Duplicates with both groups listed, but I'm not sure that it would matter for your application.

Comment: The numbers don't meed to match - the sum of the numbers need to match.  So 275 815 matches 1090 and 1655 matches 1655 and 3393 4487.26 matches 9571.26  and 100 matches 100 and then something should match 620.3 but instead 6167.91 675 8843 matches 15685.91 so that means there is no match for 620.3.

Comment: Nice edit on the question. Totals vs Summary Totals were not obvious terminology to me. I thought I was addressing the question but see now that I missed it!

Comment: I didn't down vote but I thought I had better comment on your answer and then I got brave and submitted the edit.  Is there a way to do it without VBA?

Comment: I can't find a way using SUM functions and IF statements. You need to loop through all possible SUMs. You could reasonably hard code this for ~6 totals but beyond that the formulas would be a bit silly. Your solution is much for elegant!